# Compare object array with object and reduce quantity

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object containing an id as the key, and quantity as the value, e.g.;

```
let order = {1002: 2, 1010: 1}
```

I want to compare the order object with an array of products, e.g.:

```
let stock = [{name: "test", id: "1002", quantity: 100}, {name: "moreTest", id: "1010", quantity: 100}]
```

I want to reduce the quantity for each object in my stocks array, based on the according value in the stocks object, e.g.:

```
 let newStock = [{name: "test", id: "1002", quantity: 98}, {name: "moreTest", id: "1010", quantity: 99}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Side note: `stock` shouldn't be an array, it should be a `Map` mapping IDs to objects (or if you need to support obsolete environments, an object mapping IDs to objects).

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I need to work with this setup tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a one-liner approach:

```
let newStock = stock.map(item => ({...item, quantity: item.quantity - (order[parseInt(item.id,10)] || 0)}))
```

BTW:

1. I think stock's id should be a number (or order needs to have a string key - I used parseInt but I don't think it's the best practice).
2. stock should be a map as well to prevent multiple stocks with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, very clear:

```js
let order = {1002: 2, 1010: 1}
let stock = [{name: "test", id: "1002", quantity: 100}, {name: "moreTest", id: "1010", quantity: 100}]

stock.forEach(element => {
    Object.keys(order).forEach(function(key) {
        const quantityBought = order[key];
        // == and not === because element.id is a string and key is a number
        if (element.id == key) {
            element.quantity -= quantityBought;
        }
    });
});

console.log(stock);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.reduce here something Like this

```js
let stock = [{name: "test", id: "1002", quantity: 100}, {name: "moreTest", id: "1010", quantity: 100}]

let order = {1002: 2, 1010: 1}

let result=stock.reduce((acc,value)=>{
value.quantity=value.quantity-order[value.id];
acc.push(value);
return acc;


},[])
console.log(result)
```

For reference look at array reduce function in [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)